# QGIS: make a polygon out of a line

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile of the road network.
The road are represented as polylines.
I need to load the data in a non GIS tool that allow me to color polygons in GIS files
The point is that I have lines and polylines; so the tool is not able to color them.

How do I convert a line in a whatever geometry that has some thickness, ideally in a polygon?
Poligonize and "line 2 polygon" don't work as expected

Comment: You can buffer them. Your last sentence is cut off btw.

Comment: Thank You!
I have created thanks to you the virtual layer, using this kind of query
select st_buffer(geometry,500)  from Generalized;
So at the end, this is a question similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309150/how-to-automaticaly-create-a-buffer-for-a-line-in-qgis

Comment: @MrXsquared If you have spare time please copy your comment as an answer to let met label it as the right answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buffer your lines using one of these options to turn them into polygons:

1. "Buffer" algorithm from processing toolbox
2. Expression `buffer($geometry,50)` e.g. via "Geometry by Expression" from processing toolbox or as symbology via geometry generator
3. Virtual layer or "Execute SQL" `select st_buffer(geom,50) as geometry from mylayer`

Choose a suiting distance for your needs. Keep in mind buffer distance is given in crs units of your layer.